# В чем разница между двумя одинаковыми JSON?

Tags: php, javascript, json, header

Есть два сервиса возвращающих JSON. 
1. [Первый](https://dev.cubozoa.ru/position_sl96/json_canvas_data.php)
2. [Второй](https://api.myjson.com/bins/7ar2p)

Возвращают одинаковые результаты.
Но при этом с одним график по данным JSON строится, с другим нет.
С первым не строится, со вторым строится.

Пример работы, если поменять url, будет понятно в чем проблема. 
В чем проблема? В заголовках?

```js
var dps = [], chart;
$.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/7ar2p", function(chartData) {  
 for(var i = 0; i < chartData.length; i++){
   dps.push({ x: new Date(chartData[i].x), y: chartData[i].y});
  }
 chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("wtChart", {    
   title: {
     text: "Chart from External JSON Data"
    },
    data: [
      {
        type: "column",
        dataPoints: dps
      }
    ]
  });
  chart.render();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br/><!-- Just so that JSFiddle's Result label doesn't overlap the Chart -->
<div id="wtChart" style="height: 360px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

Comment: вторая ссылка в пустоту

Comment: поправил извиняйте

Comment: Разница в заголовках `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

Comment: Да, действительно в нем.